# Ruby on Rails when using git push to openshift

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openshift

I am using open shift hosting free. Here is my simple code:

routes.rb

```
RailsApp::Application.routes.draw do 
resources: welcome
```

views>welcome>index.htm.erb

```
this is my test
```

welcome_controller.rb

```
 class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end
end
```

but still after using below code successfully

```
 git add.
 git commit -a -m 'Some commit message'
 git push
```

The main page http://myusername.rhcloud.com is available, 
but the page http://myusername.rhcloud.com/welcome/index does not exist! is like it is even not created! What problem is here?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the log file? You can check log files by running rhc tail command.

Comment: Is that code working when you run it locally?  Is your controller backed by a model & database? otherwise i don't think your resources statement would work correctly?